# Multiple UISplitViewControllers

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Hy there,

I was wondering how can I push a new uisplitviewcontroller (both master and detail) from a button in the detailviewcontroller?

[image]

Can I do this directly in the storyboard?

I tried, but it pushes the new master-detail in the uidetailViewCotroller!

Thanks

Comment: Because of the way navigation controllers work with split view controllers, it's probably easier to keep the one controller and change its data.  Or switch root controllers from the old split view to your new one.